# Harmonic 1-forms on complete non-compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete oriented Riemannian manifold. If $Ric ≥ 0$ on $M$, then any harmonic 1-form $\alpha$ is parallel i.e $x\to |\alpha|^2_{g,x}$ constant?

Comment: Did you try $\mathbb R$, with the standard metric, and $\alpha = xdx$?